# await EventSubscription certain event react native

Tags: react-native, event-handling, subscription

I am trying to wait for the event "completed" to be finished so I could return the correct value. I am using react native and the type is of `EventSubscription`

My code is like so which keeps `EventSubscription | undefined` in the values variable. How would i get the `data.responseBody` in that variable

```
const values = await Upload.startUpload(options)
    .then((uploadId) => {
      console.log("Upload started");
      Upload.addListener("progress", uploadId, (data) => {
        console.log(`Progress: ${data.progress}%`);
      });
      Upload.addListener("error", uploadId, (data) => {});
      Upload.addListener("cancelled", uploadId, (data) => {});
      const completeSub = Upload.addListener("completed", uploadId, (data) => {
        console.log("Completed!", data);
        return data.responseBody;
      });
      return completeSub;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Upload error!", err);
      return undefined;
    });
return values
```

I found a way to do this in DOM js in this link [How to let JavaScript wait until certain event happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902334/how-to-let-javascript-wait-until-certain-event-happens)